# pulling text from url and putting text back in url with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried googling this but can't find what I'm looking for. I have a url that has a number in it. I want to be able to take the number that is there and depending on what number is there then interject a name back into the url. For example:

Let's say the url is: www.example.com/video15637

Can I take that number and then do something like:

```
var nameVariable;

if(video15637){
nameVariable = video15637;
}
if(video26597){
nameVariable = video26597;
}
if(video18737){
nameVariable = video18737;
}
```

then, somehow interject the namevariable back into the url that is displayed?

Comment: In the code above, aren't you just replacing the text with an exact copy of itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'http://www.example.com/video15637';

var nameVariable = a.pathname.substr(1); // video15637
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use [**.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or combination of [**.substr()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [**.lastIndexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```
var url = 'www.example.com/video15637';
var video = url.split('/')[1];
alert(video)
```

### OR

```
var url2 = 'http://www.example.com/video15637';
var video2 = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(video2)
```

**Combined DEMO**